# Why is the formula for the expected value of two random variables the same as the formula for the volume?

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics, multivariable-calculus

[image]

[image]

What is the connection between them?

Comment: In one case two functions are multiplied in the other they are subtracted. What is here common?

Comment: @user Couldn't the final product be interpreted as a function in the same way as f(x,y)-g(x,y)? In the end you get a function either way.

Comment: In this sense all integrals have something common. :)

Comment: @user Who knows, maybe they do. Math is weird.

Comment: Maybe it's intended to be the special case $h=1-g/f$.

Comment: @J.G. What happens in that case?

Comment: Maybe I should disambiguate by instead writing $h=\frac{f-g}{f_{XY}}$, in case $f$ isn't meant to denote $f_{XY}$.

Comment: Why are you writing a difference? The expectation *is* the volume under the graph of $h(x,y)$, but $\Delta A = \Delta x\Delta y$ is weighted by a density function $f_{XY}(x,y)$. This is why expectation is a weighted average.

Comment: All integrals over regions of the $x,y$ plane have something in common and there is no "maybe" about it: every such integral has some function inside the integral, even if the function is just $h(x,y)=1.$ Also when we have two integrals over two variables there is often some way to transform one to the other, but the existence of such a transformation doesn't mean the transformation gives us any kind of useful insight into anything.

Comment: Here's another "connection" in math: I rotate a square in the plan by $m$ degrees counterclockwise, then I rotate the rotated square $n$ degrees clockwise. What's the final rotation? It's $m+n$ degrees counterclockwise. Next I put $m$ cubic meters of water in an empty tank. Then I put another $n$ cubic meters of water in the tank. How much water is in the tank? It's $m+n$ liters. Same formula! So what's the connection between rotating a square and putting water in a tank?

Comment: An observation: the product of two functions of the same variables is a function of those variables. Given $h(x,y)$ a function of $x$ and $y$, and $f_{XY}(x,y)$ also a function of $x$ and $y$, it follows that $h(x,y)f_{XY}(x,y)$ is a function of $x$ and $y$. So yes, the "final product" is a function.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this gives some intuition for the resemblance between the two concepts.

For simplicity, suppose we want to determine the volume $V$ between $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ in the cube $C = [a,b]^3$ (above the square $[a,b]^2$), where $a$ and $b$ are sufficiently large such that the volume between the functions is covered.

A rough method to do so is by throwing $n$ points in the cube $C$ and counting how much of them fell in between $f$ and $g$. The proportion of those points times the total volume of $C$ is approximately equal to $V$. If $n\to\infty$ this will equal to $V$ (at least by intuition).

To be more precise, define $X,Y,Z$ iid uniform random variables in $[a,b]$. Take $(Z_i,X_i,Y_i)$, $i=1,...,n$, iid copies of $(X,Y,Z)$. Define the approximate volume as
$$
V_n =  (b-a)^3\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\mathbb{I}(g(X_j,Y_j)\leq Z_j\leq f(X_j,Y_j)).
$$
By the law of large numbers, 
$$
V_n\overset{a.s.}{\longrightarrow}(b-a)^3E\left[\mathbb{I}(g(X,Y)\leq Z\leq f(X,Y))\right].
$$
It's not difficult to see that 
$$
E\left[\mathbb{I}(g(X,Y)\leq Z\leq f(X,Y))\right] = \dfrac{1}{(b-a)^3}\int_a^b\int_a^b(f(x,y)-g(x,y))\,dxdy.
$$
(Hint: use conditional expectation). Therefore, 
$$
V_n\overset{a.s.}{\longrightarrow}\int_a^b\int_a^b(f(x,y)-g(x,y))\,dxdy.
$$
Then we canclude that $V_n\overset{a.s.}{\longrightarrow} V$.

Comment: You are assuming that $f_{XY}(x,y)$ is $1/(b-a)^3$ in the cube and zero everywhere else--that is, you have a uniform distribution over the cube, right? I think the analogy gets quite a bit more strained if you try to deal with a non-uniform distribution.

Comment: @DavidK Yes! The important thing is to get $f-g$ in the integral, which follows immediately with uniform distributions. If you simulate with other distribution you have no guarantee of that.